# Auto-tab between fields on Django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin, field

I have an inline on a model with data with a fixed length, that has to be entered very fast, so I was thinking about a way of "tabbing" through fields automatically when the field is filled...

Could that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend the following links:

- [JQuery AutoTab](http://www.lousyllama.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab)

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible, but it will need some javascript. You'd want to bind an event to the keypress event on each field, and when it fires test the length of the text entered so far - if it matches, move the focus onto the next field.